# How do I create a related set from individual MSIXes?

Tags: installation, msix

Let us suppose that I have created two MSIX packages and that they are independent of one another. However, I want to make them into a "related set"; I want one of them to be my "main package" and the other to be an "optional package" that installs alongside the main package. I have used MakeAppx.exe to unpack both MSIX packages on my machine, and I'm looking at the two packages in the filesystem, in particular at the AppxManifest.xml files.

I know that for the optional package, the `MainPackageDependency` element (from XML namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/3`) may be added to the `Dependencies" element in AppxManifest.xml. However, I believe that in order for the two packages to form a "related set", I also need to add something to the AppxManifest.xml of the main package. I do not know what it is that I need to add there.

The focus of this question is what changes I need to make to the main package. Once those changes have been made, it would remain to re-pack the MSIXes and sign them. You may take it for granted that I know how to accomplish those steps.

The MSIXes are intended to be side-loaded (not distributed via the Microsoft Store) and they both contain executables.

### What I have tried

I have tried modifying only the package that is meant to be the "optional package" in the related set. The result of this is that when I try to install both packages, the main package installs successfully but on attempting to install the optional package, the following error message displays:

> A related set cannot be updated because the updated set is invalid. All packages in the related set must be updated at the same time. (0x80003d17)

The following error appears in the Windows error logs:

> The optional package with centennial content OptionalPackageName_21.4.0.0_x86__0rk1t7bybtkaw is not in a related set and it is required to be in a related set specified by the centennial main package MainPackageName_0rk1t7bybtkaw.

I do not know what the terms "centennial content" or "centennial main package" mean and have had no success searching for them online.

I have tried adding a `PackageDependency` element to the `Dependencies` element in the AppxManifest.xml file of the main package, with the `Optional` attribute (from XML namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10/6`) set to "true". This yielded the same results as described above. It is my understanding that this is not the correct approach because the `PackageDependency` element is used to declare so-called "Framework dependencies", which are a different kind of dependency.

I found a Microsoft documentation page that suggested that a file named "AppxBundleManifest.xml" might be the vehicle for information about optional packages. I therefore tried adding a file named "AppxBundleManifest.xml" to the main package, with content modelled on that of a file of the same name that Visual Studio created for me when I was trying to work with a sample project I downloaded from GitHub. However, this file is not packed by MakeAppx.exe when it runs; it prints the following message:

> MakeAppx : warning: Ignoring footprint file "AppxMetadata\AppxBundleManifest.xml".

I do not know what the term "footprint file" means, nor why the file is being ignored.

I have tried browsing [Microsoft's documentation of the AppxManifest.xml file schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/schema-root), but I did not notice anything helpful there.

I have tried installing a trial version of the paid-for software product "Advanced Installer", because it boasts support for this feature and I thought I might be able to crib from the MSIXes it produces. However, while I can create my optional package using this software product, I cannot figure out how to create the main package. The vendor has documentation online, but as far as I can tell they have changed the relevant parts of their application's GUI since writing that documentation, and I cannot figure out where the relevant options are in the version I downloaded. Specifically, [this page](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/optional-package-tab.html) appears to suggest that the "Builds" widget (listed under the "Package Definition" category) ought to contain an "Optional packages" tab; in fact, there is no "Optional packages" tab there.

I have tried working with [a sample project](https://github.com/AppInstaller/OptionalPackageSample) that Microsoft made available on GitHub. However, while I managed to get it to "build", I have not succeeded in getting it to create actual MSIX files. It does create AppxManifest.xml files, but there is nothing in those files that is obviously the missing element from the file in my own project.

### Why am I not using Visual Studio to create the packages?

We want to use WiX to create the MSIXes. Unfortunately, the WiX Expansion Pack does not yet support optional packages or related sets. I was hoping that there would be some tweak that we could apply to the MSIXes produced by WiX (e.g. editing the XML in the AppxManifest.xml files) that would give us what we want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What was going wrong here was that I believed erroneously that related sets could be created in the form of individual packages, compiled using MakeAppx. What you actually have to do is to use MakeAppx in two steps:

1. Use MakeAppx to create packages.
2. Use MakeAppx again to create a *bundle* from the packages you already created. (Use a "mapping file" that specifies one or more optional packages under the heading `[ExternalPackages]`)

This can be gleaned from the Microsoft documentation if you read between the lines, but it's not explicitly explained anywhere that I saw.

It's easy to gloss over the need to create bundles if you've already read about other MSIX-related topics before coming to this one, because bundles are motivated in documentation elsewhere as a means of combining together into a single unit multiple versions of your package that target different architectures. If that isn't a concern for you then you may believe you can disregard them. Well, they can be used for that purpose - but they can (indeed must) also be used if you want to create related sets. You can have a bundle that has only one essential package, and for only a single architecture.

One more gotcha: To create an msixbundle requires a minimum Windows SDK version (10.0.18362.0 I think).